# Inequality in formula solved with Lambert W

Tags: lambert-w

If I have an equation of the form $a = b \cdot e^b$ then the Lambert W function tells me that $W(a) = b$.

But what if I instead have $a \geq b \cdot e^b$ ? Do I then have $W(a) \leq b$ or $W(a) \geq b$, or does it depend on the values of $a$ and $b$?

The nature of my problem makes me believe that $W(a) \leq b$ is the right answer, but I need someone to convince me that this is the case and if possible explain why. I can't seem to find anything online. If it matters, I'm working with the -1 branch of the Lambert W function.

(The actual problem can be found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795364/how-to-isolate-alpha-in-frac-alpha-log-24-alpha) that I posted earlier, but I didn't find it to be of importance to this question)

Comment: Note that the real branch $W_0$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @gammatester, I do not see what you are hinting at.

Comment: If $a=be^b$ then $W_0(a)=b$. For positive $\epsilon$ you get 
$W_0(a+\epsilon) >  W_0(a) = b$, i.e. if $a > be^b$ you have $W(a) > b$.
Example: With $b=2$ you have $a= 14.77811220$,  check $W_0(a)=2$. Now
compute $W_0(a+0.001)=2.000045111 > 2$. If this is not you want please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. And as I am working with the -1 branch (I do mention this in the question, but should have made it more clear, sorry), which is strictly decreasing, the same reasoning will give me $W(a) \leq b$, which was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. Sorry for not using $W_{-1}$ in my comments.